# How do I update the page without f5 when I press the button in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, page-refresh, hybris-data-hub

[image]How do I update the page without f5 when I press the button in hybris?
button is in listview action, not in editorarea.

can you help me please?[image]

[image]

Comment: modelservice.refresh() alone was not enough

Comment: As said in the tag description, please "DO NOT USE THIS TAG as it's ambiguous..." The reason is the same as the tag Microsoft which does not exist, the tag SAP exists only for historical reason.

Comment: thanks but that's not really the problem right now. @SandraRossi

Answer (score 0):

You can use this java code inside your action class renderer :

```
Clients.evalJavaScript("location.reload();");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you this method refresh the page with f5 but I want to have listview or table refresh without page f5.

Comment: Can you share your action class content?

Comment: I added to question